# JavaScript: Why does overriding the toString() method of an object cause chrome to lose the object name in error messages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Given the code below:

```
/*Class with  overridden toString() */
function Stringy(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Stringy.prototype.test = function () {return 'test'};
Stringy.prototype.toString = function () {return 'Stringy'};


/*Class with default toString() */
function NoStringy(name){
    this.name = name;
}
NoStringy.prototype.test = function () {return 'test'};
```

In our Stringy class the instance's toString() works properly when forcing a conversion to string or calling the toString() method. However, the error message displays Object [object Object].

In the NoStringy class the error message has the correct object name, but uses the default Object to string method to identify it's self.

Is there no way to have a custom toString() and get the correct object Class in the error messages?  Why would overriding the toString() break this functionality?  Could this be a bug?

**I'm using Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m.**

Here is the test or check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arctelix/y89ne/):

```
test(new Stringy('Stringy instance'));
test(new NoStringy('NoStrigy instance'));

function test(i){
    var name = i.name;
    var display = document.getElementById('display');

    display.innerHTML += ('<br>----Testing: <i>' + name + '</i>-----<br>');
    display.innerHTML += (name + ': ' + i + '<br>');
    display.innerHTML += (name + '.toString(): ' + i.toString() + '<br>');
    try{
    display.innerHTML +=(name+'.foo(): '+i.foo()+'<br>')
    }
    catch(e){
    e = e.message.replace('<', '').replace('>', '');
    display.innerHTML +=(name+'.foo(): '+e+'<br>')
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
----Testing: Stringy instance-----
Stringy instance: **Stringy**
Stringy instance.toString(): Stringy
Stringy instance.foo(): **Object [object Object]** has no method 'foo'


----Testing: NoStrigy instance-----
NoStrigy instance: **[object Object]**
NoStrigy instance.toString(): [object Object]
NoStrigy instance.foo(): **Object #NoStringy** has no method 'foo'
```

The constructors in both objects point to the proper constructor so the console shows the correct constructor name as well.

console output of each instance:

```
Stringy {name: "Stringy instance", test: function, toString: function}
 - name: "Stringy instance"
 - __proto__: Stringy
   - constructor: function Stringy(name){
   - test: function () {return 'test'}
   - toString: function () {return 'Stringy'}
   - __proto__: Object

NoStringy {name: "NoStrigy instance", test: function}
 - name: "NoStrigy instance"
 - __proto__: NoStringy
   - constructor: function NoStringy(name){
   - test: function () {return 'test'}
   - __proto__: Object
```

I have opened a ticket: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=348865

Comment: I'm getting `Stringy instance.foo(): i.foo is not a function` and `NoStrigy instance.foo(): i.foo is not a function` (Firefox 27)

Comment: The difference is that calling `object.toString()` is different than what internal JS might call. Don't forget, there's always `Object.prototype.toString.call(object)`, which is what seems to be called here. This has nothing to do with errors/error messages

Comment: @Ian It's obvious that inernal JS is not using object.toString when it constructs the error message.  It is also not calling Object.prototype.toString.call(object), i updated the fiddle tests.  The question is, when chrome constructs the error message, where does it get the object value from and why does overriding toString() in the prototype change the error output to Object [object Object]....

Comment: @DavidKnipe this question only applies to versions of chrome that make a reference to the object in the error message. I am using Chrome v 33.